# Why isn't swing calling toString() on the objects I pass to a JComboBox?

Tags: java, python, swing, jython, tostring

I have this class to represent choices in a combobox:

```
class Choice(object):
    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label

    def toString(self):
        print "in Choice.toString" #for debugging
        return self.label
```

I have an array of `Choice` objects, and I want to show the label values in a JComboBox, but be able to retrieve the id later, after the array has gone out of scope.

On the subject of JComboBox renderers, [the Java Swing tutorial says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer),

> The default renderer knows how to render strings and icons. If you put other objects in a combo box, the default renderer calls the toString method to provide a string to display.

So, given that I've added a `toString()` method to my `Choice` class, I should just be able to do this:

```
choices = [Choice(1, 'foo'), Choice(3, 'bar'), Choice(5, 'baz')]
combo = JComboBox(choices)
```

and then later:

```
pickedId = combo.getSelectedItem().id
```

However, the text that shows in my combo is like `<command.Choice object at 0x2>`, and that `print` statement that I've put into `Choice.toString()` never happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python/jython, but maybe the toString() method which you create doesn't extend "void Object.toString()" (maybe the signature doesn't match).  Try inspecting the compiled class using javap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! On the back of Atrey's answer and JimN's comment, I found out that Python's equivalent to `toString()` is actually `__repr__`.

So my class now looks like:

```
class Choice(object):
    def __init__(self, id, label):
        self.id = id
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label
```

Comment: That's interesting, in that `__repr__` is supposed to return a python code to recreate the object, while `__str__` is supposed to return a more natural representation of the object.  Good find!

Comment: @Atreys the "return code that can recreate the object" idea has been discredited for a while; it turned out to be a bad idea (or at least unfeasible) in too many cases.

Answer (score 2):

You should override `__str__(self)` in your python class.

Comment: (a hypothesis. `toString` is for Java.  `__str__` is for python)

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out the equivalent to `toString` is not `__str__` but `__repr__`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)